# Is it possible to create Scrapy Spiders programmatically through the API?

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

We are investigating the suitability of Scrapy in a system where non-technical end users would create new scraping tasks through a web UI, e.g. a user might specify to scrape example.com/foo weekly, where this is a completely new spider.

This would require our system to tell Scrapy about this new spider programmatically, instead of the typical usage where a file is manually crafted which defines a new Spider class.

In reviewing the api documents it appears that SpiderLoader may do what we need, but I can't find any concrete examples of this that confirm for me this is the approach. Can anyone confirm this is the case or if not, please advise on the general approach to this problem, or point to a example somewher?

Comment: Instead of using a custom SpiderLoader, I would use a custom spider that loads its extraction logic from a web-UI-generated file. That, or create an actual spider from the web-UI settings.

Comment: So instantiate a Spider class?  Use the Crawler API?  I don't understand your response.  Can you provide a line of code that shows which API you're talking about (Crawler API?  Settings API?) and which class?  thanks

Comment: I don’t think _I_ understood your question. You say “This would require our system to tell Scrapy about this new spider programmatically”. Does this mean that you are (would be?) already creating the spider, and your problem is reporting that it exists to Scrapy?